# Apply a dynamically created lambda to an object instance

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I have some code which dynamically create a lambda starting from strings. For example, I have a filter class like the following:

```
public class Criteria {
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I am able to create a lambda like `x => x.Name == "Foo"` starting from a Criteria instance like this

```
Criteria c = new Criteria() {
    Property = "Name",
    Operator = "equal",
    Value = "Foo"
}
```

Supposing to have a class like

```
public class Receipt {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    [other props omitted]
    public ICollection<ReceiptDetail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to:

1. Apply the lambda to any object (I know that the lambda should be created with a ParameterExpression of the Receipt class)
2. Getting back the boolean result of the lambda (e.g. Is the name equals to Foo?)
3. Apply the same logic to collections Count() method (e.g. Building a lambda which checks against receipt.Details.Count()

Is this possible?

**EDIT**: As per the comments, I am elaborating my needs a bit more. This code will give me the chance to answer to a requirement that I have and that says: If there is a rule specified for my object then the application should behave a bit differently. While this is a common requirement, I would like to create a code which will permit me to extend it as more rules will be added. Actually I only have 5 rule types:

- Verify if the input comes in a specific day of the week
- Verify if the input comes in a specific time range
- Verify if the field "X" of the input is less/equal/greather than a value
- Verify if the field "Y" of the input contains a value
- Verify if the field "Z" of the input, which is a collection, has a count that is less/equal/greather than a value

For the first 4 points I have been able to dynamically create a lambda expression, with code like in [P.Brian.Mackey answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29044926/431537), which I could apply, using the Specification pattern, to the object itself.

The last point needs to be implemented almost in the same way but the only difference is that the left part of the expression was a method call and not a Property (specifically the `ICollection<T>.Count()` method)

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: I am sorry but I donth think that the suggested link will solve my problem

Comment: Possible yes.  Non-trivial.

Comment: "And I am able to create a lambda like x => x.Name == "Foo" starting from a Criteria instance like this..." Is the lambda you create just a string?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: No. Is an instance of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`

Comment: Can this be done with dynamic linq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something to get you started.  There is plenty of room for improvement.  Especially the ugly factory.  This demo is intended to show how to use Expressions to solve the problems, not as a best practices or factory pattern demo.  If anything is unclear please feel free to ask for clarification.

#### Usage

```
    [Test]
    public void ApplySameLogicToCollectionsCount()
    {
        var receipt = new Receipt();
        var details = new ReceiptDetail();
        var details2 = new ReceiptDetail();
        receipt.Details.Add(details);
        receipt.Details.Add(details2);
        var result = LambdaGeneratorFactory<ICollection<ReceiptDetail>>.Run(detailsCount);
        Assert.IsTrue(result(receipt.Details));
    }
```

#### Factory

```
 public static class LambdaGeneratorFactory<T>
    {
        //This is an ugly implementation of a Factory pattern.
        //You should improve this possibly with interfaces, maybe abstract factory.  I'd start with an ICriteria.
        public static Predicate<T> Run(Criteria criteria)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof (Receipt))
            {
                return CreateLambda(criteria);
            }
            else if (typeof (T) == typeof (ICollection<ReceiptDetail>))
            {
                return CreateLambdaWithCount(criteria);
            }

            return null;
        }
        private static Predicate<T> CreateLambda(Criteria criteria)
        {
            ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "i");

            Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(T).GetProperty(criteria.Property));
            Expression right = Expression.Constant(criteria.Value);

            Expression predicateBody = Expression.Equal(left, right);

            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Predicate<T>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }).Compile();

            return predicate;
        }

        private static Predicate<T> CreateLambdaWithCount(Criteria criteria)
        {
            ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "i");

            Expression count = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(T).GetProperty("Count"));
            Expression left = Expression.Call(count, typeof(Object).GetMethod("ToString"));
            Expression right = Expression.Constant(criteria.Value);

            Expression predicateBody = Expression.Equal(left, right);

            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Predicate<T>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }).Compile();

            return predicate;
        }
    }
```

#### Criteria

```
    private Criteria detailsCount = new Criteria()
    {
        Property = "Details",
        Operator = "equal",
        Value = "2"
    };
```

Switch to `ICriteria` and things will b cleaner.  A better factory and no need for `ToString`.  Program to an interface.

***All that being said, this code feels a bit funky.  What is the point of generating functions from strings?  I get the feeling this is heading towards generating C# from a grammar.  I'm not convinced that will scale well. For non-trivial implementations consider [lex/yacc](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Lex-YACC-HOWTO-4.html) first.  You can find more details for doing this in the [Pragmatic Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020161622X) "Implementing a mini language".***

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I have edited my question to give you a better undestanding of the problem. I am not going to create a grammar that, an I completely agree with you, would need a better method (like the lex/yacc reference you gave).

Comment: One more thing. I am trying to call the method `Count()` not just the property `Count`.

Comment: @Lorenzo this is what Brian is referring to when he says that it does not scale well. The "method" `.Count()` is rather more complicated than at first glance. Do you mean `List.Count()` or do you mean `Enumerable.Count(this IEnumerable)`? How does your factory code know to look in `System.Linq.Enumerable`? At this point we are rapidly descending into the realm of a full .net language specification. Given that is the case, why not just use one of the many .net languages that already exists?

Comment: @Aron: Unfortunately at first I did not fully understood the hidden caveats that Brian answer was referring to. I did'nt realized that in effect there is more than one `Count()` method around. I wanted to use `Enumerable.Count( this IEnumerable )` but in effect is not so easy as I thought. I think I will switch to the property as Brian suggested. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a fascinating question, and I'd like to understand the requirements. I created a demo, and I'm wondering, how does the demo differ from what you're trying to accomplish? There is a working version here https://dotnetfiddle.net/AEBZ1w too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Criteria c = new Criteria() { 
            Property = "Name", 
            Operator = "==", 
            Value = "Foo" };

        var queryable = (new List<Receipt>() { 
            new Receipt { Name = "Foo", Amount = 1 },
            new Receipt { Name = "Foo", Amount = 2 }, 
            new Receipt { Name = "Bar" }  
        }).AsQueryable();

        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Receipt), "x");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, typeof(Receipt).GetProperty(c.Property));
        var constant = Expression.Constant(c.Value);
        var operation = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
        var expression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { queryable.ElementType },
            queryable.Expression, 
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Receipt, bool>>(operation, new ParameterExpression[] { parameter })
        );

        Console.WriteLine("Linq Expression: {0} \n", expression.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Results: \n");

        var results = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<Receipt>(expression);
        foreach(var r in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", r.Name, r.Amount);
        }
    }
}

public class Criteria
{
    public string Property, Operator, Value;
}

public class ReceiptDetail
{
    public string ItemName;
}

public class Receipt
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount;
    public ICollection<ReceiptDetail> Details;
}
```

References

- [How to: Execute Expression Trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882536.aspx)
- [How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx)
- [IQueryable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.iqueryable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Expression Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298334%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Expression.Property Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.property%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. Actually it does not differ a lot from my actual implementation except from the fact that, regarding the first two points of the question, I was trying to use the expression to "Validate" a Receipt object which is a little bit different from using the expression to "select" object of type Receipt. I have been able to solve this however by using the expression like `expression.Compile()(receipt)` which returns a bool value that says if the `receipt` instance satisfy the expression. The third question however is a bit more complex and Brian got the point

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection with generics. One way to solve the problem could be an extension

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Criteria c)
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(T);
        var propertyMember = sourceType.GetProperty(c.Property);
        Func<string, bool> predicate = null;
        switch (c.Operator)
        {
            case "equal":
                predicate = (v) => v == c.Value;
                break;
            // other operators
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported operator.");
        }
        return source.Where(v => predicate((string)propertyMember.GetMethod.Invoke(v, null)));
    }
}
```

Which you could make use of in your code:

```
    void FooBar()
    {
        Criteria c = new Criteria()
        {
            Property = "Name",
            Operator = "equal",
            Value = "foo"
        };

        var source = new Receipt[2];
        source[0] = new Receipt { Name = "foo", Amount = 1 };
        source[1] = new Receipt { Name = "bar", Amount = 2 };

        var result = source.Where(c);
    }
```

This is just to give you an idea. Improvements would be error handling (property not found, invalid cast, null values, etc.), refactoring to enable unit testing (e.g. inject the select "strategy") and performance (e.g. building, compiling and caching expression trees instead of reflection). This should give you enough keywords to learn about. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not exactly what I want. I am already able to pass the constructed lambda to a Where method and get back the results. What I wanted to do is to execute the lambda against a single instance of Receipt and get back the true/false result.

Comment: Could you give an example how the code could look like should the compiler allow it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure that I have undertood your question. I have added some details to the question however.